# Proving that a set of matrices is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, abelian-groups

> Prove that the set of matrices in the form of
>    $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha
>  &\cos \alpha \end{array}\right]$ (while $\alpha \in R$) with the
>   operation of matrix multiplication is an abelian group.

Could someone please point me some direction? I know how to multiply matrices or what's the definition of an abelian group but... How can I apply it here? And show such thing, for such a large group of possible alphas?

EDIT: OK, so thanks to your advices, I tried to move a little but I think I don't get the idea behind it... On Wikipedia, one can find that "For all a, b in A, the result of the operation a • b is also in A." - does that mean I have to try multiply every term from the matrix by every other? I mean: $cos \alpha \cdot sin \alpha$ and so on? Or did I get it all wrong?

Comment: You are also going to need this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities That might be all you'll need.

Comment: Don't worry about such a "large group of possible alphas."  Just show that for any choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the corresponding matrices commute.  We don't need to go through all possible pairs of real numbers, just a generic pair.

Comment: The group operation here is the usual matrix multiplication. Crunch the numbers to prove that the product of the matrices of the form you've given has the same form.

Comment: So is multiplying two matrices - one with alphas, one with betas - and showing that it produces something in the similar form but with the variables' sums inside the respective funcitons - enough to show that it's an abelian group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addition formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\alpha)&-\sin(\alpha)\\
\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\beta)&-\sin(\beta)\\
\sin(\beta)&\cos(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
&-\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\
\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
&\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\alpha+\beta)&-\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\
\sin(\alpha+\beta)&\cos(\alpha+\beta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
The rest of the group requirements are pretty immediate after this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm starting to get the grasp of it. However, I have a question: the first axiom states, for example, that "For all a, b in A, the result of the operation a • b is also in A." - but how does the final matrix show me this? I mean: we multiply two generic matrices by themselves, get a new matrix - but how can show some example axiom on such matrix?

Comment: @Straightfw: Perhaps I am missing where your confusion lies, but if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\alpha+\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the bottom matrix is of the same form as the general form you give. The matrix for $\alpha=0$ is easily the identity of the group (and the identity matrix). The matrix for $-\alpha$ is the inverse of the matrix for $\alpha$. etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - my confusion lies in how can I use the bottom matrix to show each of the five axioms (which I must do to prove it, right?). I mean: is saying that if α∈R and β∈R, then α+β∈R sufficient for the example axiom I posted?

Comment: List the axioms. We have verified that there is an identity, there are inverses, closure under multiplication, the group is abelian since $\alpha+\beta=\beta+\alpha$.

Comment: I meant these axioms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Definition - don't I have to somehow show each one to prove that the group is abelian?

Comment: I've just gone through everything but showing associativity. Since addition on $\mathbb{R}$ is associative, it immediately shows the multiplication on these matrices is associative. You don't even need to use the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: Great, I think I may get at least a part of it. Thank you a lot for your help and patience! :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your list of group axioms, and get cranking.  Trig identities will be your friend.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please care to take a look at my edit in original post? I believe I'm stuck at the very basics...

Answer (score 3):

That it is an group is obvious, the set is $SO(2)$, the only thing you need to prove is that it is abelian. 
Just compute the product to see it.

The special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ is the group of all matrices such that 
$$O \cdot O^T = O^T \cdot O= I$$ and $\det(O)=1$.

So we have 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
a & c\\ b & d \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
So we have
\begin{align*}
1&=a^2 +b^2 \\
0&= ac + bd\\
0&= ac + bd\\
1&= c^2+d^2 \\ 
\end{align*}
and $$\det 
\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\c & d \\ \end{pmatrix}=ad -bc=1$$

As 
$$1=\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)=a^2 +b^2 $$
As $a\in(-1,1)$ you can chose $\alpha$ such that $\cos(\alpha)=a$ and we know that $b=\pm \sin(\alpha)$. It follows that $d=\cos(\alpha)$ and $c=-b$.

So your set ist just that group. Now we only need to prove it is a group.
At first we show that the general linear group is a group. The general linear group are all invertible $n\times n$ matrices and called $GL_n$ together with the matrix multiplication.

That the matrix multiplication is associative is obvious as the composition of functions is associative and the matric multiplication is the composition of two linear functions. The neutral element ist the identiy matrix, and every element has an inverse as we definied the group to be all invertible matrices, and as the inverse of a matrix is invertible the inverses are in $GL_n$ too. We need to prove that the set is closed under multiplication, as we know that 
$$\det(A\cdot B)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$$
and $\det(A)\neq 0 \neq \det(B)$ we see it is closed under multiplication.

Hence $GL_n$ is a group, now we show that $SO(n)$ is a subgroup of $GL_n$.

It is closed under multiplication as 
$$(AB)^T = B^T A^T$$
and $$B^T A^T A B = I$$ 
when $A^T A=I$ and $B^T B=I$
and $1\cdot 1 =1$.

Hence $SO(n)$ is a group with matrix multiplication.

And as
$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha)\\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)\\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\beta) & -\sin(\beta)\\ \sin(\beta)& \cos(\beta)\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) 
& -(\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\\  (\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)& \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I think you have it backwards: you need trig identities to show it's closed under multiplication, while commutativity follows from very generic computations.

Comment: oh right, messed up, the set is just SO(2) isn't it ?

Comment: Sure it is, but I highly doubt the OP is familiar with this terminology, nor is operating at the level where it can be taken for granted that this is a group.

Comment: do you think he know that the general linear group is a group ?

Comment: I think it is highly likely he/she has never even heard the term "general linear group", given that the OP sounds slightly baffled by the cardinality of the present group.  IMO, it's just as "obvious" that $SO(2)$ is abelian, which is to say not really.

Comment: @erick added some details

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, what you're writing here is way above my level - could you please care to take a look at my edit in original post? I believe I'm stuck at the very basics...

Answer (score 2):

An idea for another approach: define the abelian group

$$T:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=1\iff z=e^{i\alpha}\;,\;\alpha\in\Bbb R\}\;,\;\text{and the map}\;\;\phi: T\to SO_2(\Bbb R)\;\text{defined by}$$

$$\phi(e^{i\alpha}):=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&\!\!-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha&\;\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$
Check the above is an onto set map and  it induces an operation on $\,SO_2(\Bbb R)\,$ taking product of matrices (as expected) and making this last set into a group which is then trivially abelian.

Comment: Oh my, I don't have the slightest idea about what you proposed here... Thank you but I doubt it's my level of thinking  :(

Comment: Perhaps it isn't your level of mathematics...and that's why it is always a good idea to add some background to know that you're expecting. BTW, the above is *not* high level stuff at all: a little complex numbers and basic group and set theory...